# Fibonacci haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fibonacci

I begin a "new" Fibonacci algorithm, but it's not working. It's very simple:

```
    --fiblista 0 n = [0]
    --fiblista 1 n = [1]
    fiblista a n 
        | a <= n = (0:1:tail, ((fiblista!!d)+(fiblista!!c))) fiblista a+1 n 
        where d = a - 1 
              c = a - 2
```

Example:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27560194/example.png]

First error code:    parse error on input `='

Any idea how to fix this algorithm?
I read thousand of example Fibonacci algorithm in haskell, but I need to write a new one.

Comment: Could you try to explain your approach? There are so many syntax and type errors here that I'm having trouble seeing how you meant for this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. Try:

```
fiblista 0 n = [0]
fiblista 1 n = [1]
fiblista a n 
    | a < n = (tail, ((fiblista!!d)+(fiblista!!c))) fiblista a+1 n 
  where d = a - 1 
        c = a - 2
```

But this code still won't compile. `fiblista` is a function with two parameters, but you also try to use it as a list. You also try to use a tuple as a function.

If you are still stuck writing your function, it would help if you could describe what the parameters to `fiblista` are, and what it should return. Include a type signature.

Is this homework?

---

So.

`fiblista a n` is a list of Fibonacci numbers, starting with the *a*<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number, and ending with the (*n*-1)<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number.

This is a list question.

[Imagine you had a list of all the Fibonacci numbers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence#Using_the_infinite_list_of_Fibonacci_numbers). (This would be the same as `fiblista 0 ∞`, if `∞` was a valid Haskell value.) You would then be able to use the standard list functions [`take`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.4.1.0/Prelude.html#v%3atake) and [`drop`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.4.1.0/Prelude.html#v%3adrop) to calculate `fiblista a n`.

Comment: Thanks the answer, a means the a-th fibonacci number, the n is the last fibonacci number, the function should return a list with n fibonacci number. not homework just learning haskell with my own way. My previous question is a homework question this is not.

Comment: What do you mean by the "last" Fibonacci number? How does the output `fiblista` depend on `a`? Please describe what your function should return on general inputs precisely.

Comment: @deszhtop If I understand your diagram, you want `fiblista 4 5 = [3]` and `fiblista 3 5 = [2,3]` but `fiblista 2 5 = [0,1,1,2,3]`. Why not `fiblista 2 5 = [1,2,3]`?